# WSO2 API Manager : Listing, Editing and Removing API Keys used for Authorization

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am securing my API using API Key, which I am able to do, i.e I am able to generate the apiKeys and use it but **how do I delete the keys or edit the keys?** (for ex enhance/change the scope of IP Restrictions, etc)

I followed the below article to implement it. It doesn't talk about editing, deleting keys -
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/learn/api-security/api-authentication/secure-apis-using-api-keys/

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke the API key using the REST API in [1] and then regenerate API key with new changes.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.0.0/develop/product-apis/devportal-apis/devportal-v1/devportal-v1/#/API%20Keys/post_applications__applicationId__api_keys__keyType__revoke